# Can I mirror a website and change the URL paths?

Tags: domains, subdomain

Is it possible to mirror a website under a different domain with different subpage urls?

For example:

`domain-a.example/mainpage`

becomes
`domain-b.example/domain-a-mainpage`

In this scenario domain b should always update new pages dynamically when new content is added to domain-a?

Is something like this possible assuming I have access to both domains?

Comment: Are they both your own websites?

Comment: Yes, well, I have access to their webmasters who can make any required changes on their side.

Comment: Does it need to be an entirely separate "mirror"? You could theoretically have 1 website with 2 domains and 2 URL structures. (?)

Comment: Why wouldn't you think you might be able to do do this?   You might have to write some custom proxy code, but I don't see any reason why it couldn't be done.